# Reusable Form Modal for Razor Pages table list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

First of: I cannot use blazor as of now. I have a razor page application that list items from the database. Each of these items have a form that they can edit. I know this can be done if you go to a new page. What I am trying to accomplish is to use one modal for all the forms in the table.

```
                            <tbody>
                                @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.List.Count; i++)
                                {

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a>@Model.AddressList[i].Description</a></td>
                                        <td>@Model.List[i].Address1 </td>
                                        <td>@Model.List[i].City</td>
                                        <td>@Model.List[i].StateAbbr</td>
                                        <td>@Model.List[i].Zipcode</td>
                                        <td>@Model.List[i].CountryAbbr</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" 
                                         data-target="#addressModal">Edit</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```

Each tr has its button to call this modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addressModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">...
```

I know razor  and html are rendered separately, but I was hoping there was a way to to do this without having to go to a new page or write a lot of javascript?

Comment: Hi @Daniel,not sure how many models in your application.If your application contains some models,you could create a partial view with a view model which contains these models.But if you contains many models and they all need to be edit,the partial view be contain many code,it may cause low performance.The better way I could consider is using partial view to reuse the form and avoid coding the same code serveral times.If you accept this suggestion I will share a simple demo for you.

Comment: Yes, please share a sample.